# Why the packet loss of ping and traceroute is different

Tags: ping, packetloss, traceroute

I have an IP address on 12th hop. When I send an icmp request packet with TTL 11 to this IP, the packet loss at the 11th hop is 0%.

However, if I ping the IP address of the 11th hop, or use TTL 11 to build my icmp request packet to trace the 11th hop, the packet loss will exceed 20%.

I don't understand the cause of this result. Is there a difference between the router's handling of reply packets and time exceed packets?

Or I should use ping to calculate the packet loss delay after obtaining the destination IP routing path like pathping, but not keep traceroute?

Sorry, for some reason I can't paste my output, but my output looks like this. The ip of 1st to 10th hop is the same.

```
trace 123.123.123.124       
IP             TTL  Loss
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1   0%
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 2   0%
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 3   0%
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 4   0%
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 5   0%
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 6   0%
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 7   0%
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 8   0%
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 9   0%
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 10  0%
123.123.123.123 11  0%
123.123.123.124 12  20%

trace 123.123.123.123       
IP             TTL  Loss
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1   0%
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 2   0%
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 3   0%
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 4   0%
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 5   0%
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 6   0%
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 7   0%
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 8   0%
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 9   0%
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 10  0%
123.123.123.123 11  20%

ping 123.123.123.123 loss 20%
```

Answer (score 0):

IP traffic does not necessarily follow the same path. So in the case of traceroute that is sending ICMP packets, they don't always necessarily follow the same path too (ICMP runs on top of IP). That's why you have different results.